# USSD Menus Dont Work

Tags: functionality

USSD menus don't work on my phone. The initial request goes through fine e.g. a balance enquiry, but if menu options are returned i.e. the USSD session stays open, then the phone appears to hang and then timeout, simply returning some garbled characters to the user.

I'd love to post a screenshot but WP7 doesnt support that :P Does anyone else have this problem or just me on African networks? Thanks!

Comment: See http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-wpdevices/wp7-ussd-issue/9e002eb8-e8cf-42cc-b47c-4dceda85e7e6, it seems it might be a known issues, eventually some hints help

Comment: What do you mean by "USSD"?

Comment: You are correct, those menus do not work on WP7. I struggled with my parents phones, wondering why the request would not go through, and was all ready to march down to ******* and demand an explanation, and then I just dialled the voice service for recharging etc :) so now my parents just use that for bundle purchases etc.

Comment: @RowlandShaw the OP means the operator service menu, e.g. *111#, *101# etc, as well as the sim card applications menu.

Answer (score 2):

It's not just you, some USSD functions are not supported. You can upvote [the relevant feature request](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2280103-ussd-support)